# ¿Como clic a un elemento del reCaptcha con Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, recaptcha

**Hola**

Tengo el problema que quiero poder manipular el **reCaptcha v2** usando **Selenium** pero no logro hacer clic en un elemento dentro.

**Mi código:**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'a-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]")));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.rc-anchor-content"))).click();

new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'c-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]")));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"recaptcha-reload-button\"]"))).click();
```

Mi código logra encontrar el **Captcha** y hacer clic y en teoría debería poder encontrar el otro **iframe** donde se muestran las opciones e imágenes. Pero no lo obtiene y por lo tanto no puede hacer clic en el botón **reload**.

**El error presente en consola:**

> *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'c-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]}   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$17.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:501)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$17.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:497)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
>     ... 36 more console.error: "Store does not have a valid reducer. Make
>   sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values
>   are reducers."

Comment: Tienes alguna URL donde se utilice el mismo captcha? Este en lace puede servir para intentarlo o es otro captcha? https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que tienes que volver al contenido por defecto entre una accion sobre un iframe y el siguiente:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'a-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]")));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.rc-anchor-content"))).click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'c-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]")));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"recaptcha-reload-button\"]"))).click();
```

El segundo frame no es visible desde el primero, pero si desde el contenido por defecto.

Por explicar un poco mejor los pasos:

DC -> iFrame A -> DC -> iFrame C

Comment: Gracias amigo pero me arroja el mismo error `Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'c-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]}`

Comment: Yo he copiado tu codigo y he hecho la prueba sobre el enlace que te he puesto y funciona. Si pudieras compartir una URL donde este el mismo captcha podria estudiar el error. https://recaptcha-demo.appspot.com/recaptcha-v2-checkbox-explicit.php

Comment: WebDriverWait esta obsoleto compañero lo correcto seria usar timeout del del driver. driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3000);

Comment: Si tienes que esperar explixitamente usa   Thread.Sleep(1000); y asunto resuelto.